# java MockRestServiceServer escape characters in url

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In our project we're using external system with quite unusual REST API.
It contains square brackets in the url:

```
api/v1/series?match[]=up
```

Now we want to test our own REST api and just to mock this external system's responses.
So we're using MockRestServiceServer object in our unit tests.

```
    mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.manyTimes(), requestTo(UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(prometheusURL + "series?match[]=up")
            .build().toUri()))
            .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(promResponseMetricUpInfo, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Inside our Service we just call this external API as

```
restTemplate.getForObject(prometheusURL + "series?match[]=up", ResponseObjectForSeries.class);
```

But as a result we have the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected request expected:<http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?match[]=up> but was:<http://localhost:9090/api/v1/series?match%5B%5D=up>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.web.client.match.MockRestRequestMatchers$5.match(MockRestRequestMatchers.java:121) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.web.client.DefaultRequestExpectation.match(DefaultRequestExpectation.java:84) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.web.client.SimpleRequestExpectationManager.validateRequestInternal(SimpleRequestExpectationManager.java:55) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.web.client.AbstractRequestExpectationManager.validateRequest(AbstractRequestExpectationManager.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.web.client.MockRestServiceServer$MockClientHttpRequestFactory$1.executeInternal(MockRestServiceServer.java:289) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.mock.http.client.MockClientHttpRequest.execute(MockClientHttpRequest.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
```

How can we escape these square brackets?
I tried to use backslashes or %5B%5D explicity in the test. But it doesn't help.

Comment: How do you try %5B%5D explicitly? Do you mind to share the code with us?

Comment: I mean I've just written mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.manyTimes(), requestTo(UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(prometheusURL + "series?match%5B%5D=up"). But these symbols were also encoded. So square brackets were encoded twice

Comment: If you remove toUri() it works?

Answer (score 0):

This problem resolved using

```
URLEncoder.encode()
```

in tests